# Migrating from RichFaces 3.x to RichFaces 4.x causes error parsing a4j.taglib.xml

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets

I have downloaded the `richfaces-components-ui-4.3.1.Final.jar` and pasted it in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and also the other JARs required for RichFaces 4. In spite of that, I am getting the below mentioned error during deployment:

```
java.io.IOException: Error parsing jar:file:/C:/new_jboss-portal-2.7.2/jboss-portal-2.7.2/server/default/temp/deploy/tmp1275818846018948934BMS-exp.war
/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.3.1.Final.jar!/META-INF/a4j.taglib.xml
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: could you check your java version and if rich faces 4 are compatible on that version please

Comment: yes it is compatible,I'm using jdk1.6 which is compatible with Rich Faces 4

Comment: Can you post your complete error log ?

Comment: In the future please post the full stack trace. This way one would immediately see `com.sun.facelets` classes causing this error which would in turn be a great hint that you're still using Facelets 1.x. JSF 2.0 Facelets is namely packaged in `com.sun.faces.facelets`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different RichFaces versions in classpath: Richfaces 3.x and 4.x so the problem is most probably due to version conflict. Try removing Richfaces 3.x and check.

Comment: no there is only Rich Faces 4.x,I have removed all the jars of rich Faces 3.x,I'm using only rich faces 4.x version,inspite of that getting this error

Comment: do you have any other war at the same location ?

Comment: have you checked that in your old deployed war files inside the temp ?

Comment: before deployment I used to delte the previous version temp,work folder from JBoss Portal server directory

Comment: As far as I see your error log, the reason is the version conflict for sure, now you need to check where else you've used Richfaces 3.x in your previous projects. Just post the complete log in your question so that others can see and help you out over the same.

Comment: Its not a jdk issue at all, its a conflict of your old richfaces jars with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

> Error parsing jar: ...  a4j.taglib.xml

This is recognizable as a Facelets parsing error. It failed to parse the RichFaces4's `a4j.taglib.xml`. RichFaces4 is a JSF 2.0 compatible component library. JSF 2.0 has Facelets 2.0 bundled. This parsing error suggests that you've still Facelets 1.x around in your classpath which doesn't recognize Facelets 2.0 compatible taglib files.

Get rid of all Facelets 1.x related JAR files (`jsf-facelets.jar`) and all Facelets 1.x specific configuration, particularly the `FaceletViewHandler` in the `faces-config.xml`. This is namely suppressing Facelets 2.0 from running. Once you get rid of all Facelets 1.x artifacts, then Facelets 2.0 will run and successfully parse the taglib file.

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/4532870#4532870)